# Trouble dealing with header in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written some code using python to scrape some titles and price from a webpage and write the results in a csv file. The script is running awesome. As I'm appending data to a csv file the script is writing headers in such a way that if it runs 4 loops then the headers will be written 4 times. How to fix it so that the headers will be written once. Thanks.

This is the script:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

diction_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND','http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

for link in diction_page:
    res = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
    title = soup.select_one('.name').text.strip()
    price = soup.select_one('.price').text
    print(title,price)
    with open('item.csv','a',newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(["Title","Price"])
        writer.writerow([title, price])
```

Comment: Would it be a problem to move `writer.writerow(["Title","Price"])` outside of the loop? You could either keep one file context for the entire loop or write the headers, close the file and continue to the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can try this:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

diction_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND','http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

for i,link in enumerate(diction_page):
    res = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
    title = soup.select_one('.name').text.strip()
    price = soup.select_one('.price').text
    print(title,price)
    with open('item.csv','a',newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        if (i == 0):
            writer.writerow(["Title","Price"])
        writer.writerow([title, price])
```

Comment: Thanks Fidan, for this great workaround. I was expecting something like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more things to know : What to do when there is a range to deal with in a for loop as in `for i,year in enumerate(range(1947,1950),1):`. I tried it but it doesn't work in this case. Did I do it accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: Second arg in **enumerate** function used for start num **i**. Check this out [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Do you really wanted to start **i** from 1, not from zero?

Comment: @ Fidan, Thanks god, you responded. I know nothing of enumerate. I tried few different ways but found wrong results. Just give me an idea how to write there the header which won't be repeated. Please care to check out this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7u039c75lytouwk/for%20Fidan.txt?dl=0  Thanks again.

Comment: I think @Ken Wei's corrected answer will be much better and correct for you. 
Just keep file open, write header and then at loops write your data.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write the headers in the for loop:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

diction_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND','http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

outfile = open('item.csv','w',newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Title","Price"])

for link in diction_page:
    res = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
    title = soup.select_one('.name').text.strip()
    price = soup.select_one('.price').text
    print(title,price)
    writer.writerow([title, price])
outfile.close()
```

Comment: why not leaving the file open instead of appending in the loop?

Comment: @ Ken Wei, I used your suggested method earlier and in this case `with open('item.csv','a',newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)` is completely redundant. Thanks anyway.